# Android progress dialog from does not update from asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an progress dialog inside an PreferenceFragment and does not update its progress:

The progress dialog is initialized inside the following listener

```
 @Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
     if (getString(R.string.sync).equalsIgnoreCase(preference.getKey())) {
        String saveTitle = getString(R.string.crop__wait);
        String saveDescription = getString(R.string.sync_is_running);
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), saveTitle, saveDescription, false, true);
        progressDialog.setProgress(10);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.show();
        new SyncAsyncTask(this).execute();
        return true;
    } else  if (getString(R.string.changePassword).equalsIgnoreCase(preference.getKey())) {
        ChangePasswordDialog.createDialog(getString(R.string.changePassword)).show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "YES_NO_DIALOG");
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And here I am updating the progress dialog, but on ui does not appear  any progress. Appears just the following parts of the ProgressDialog: the title, the description and the spinner.

```
@Override
    public void updateProgress(int progress) {
        total += progress;
        progressDialog.setProgress(total);
        progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(total);

    }
```

Strange fact is that this code making the progress visible:

```
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (getActivity());
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.setTitle(saveTitle);
    progressDialog.setMessage(saveDescription);
    progressDialog.setMax(100);
    progressDialog.show();
```

I am also posting the async task code, but I am sure that is fine:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class SyncAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    private WeakReference<ISyncronizable> ref = null;
    private final int totalCount = 21;

    public SyncAsyncTask(ISyncronizable syncronizable) {
        ref = new WeakReference<>(syncronizable);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (ref.get().getContext() != null) {
            return synchronizeDB(ref.get().getContext());
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {      
        if (ref.get().getContext() != null) {
            ref.get().finishedSyncronization(result);
            ref.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        ref.get().updateProgress(values[0]);
    }

    public boolean synchronizeDB(final Context context) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        SoapSyncService ss = SoapSyncService.getSoapSyncService();
        boolean successfullSync = true;

        SystemSettingBean systemSettingsBean = SQLMceHelper.getDb(context).getLatestSyncDate();

        Date date = cal.getTime();
        String serverDateAndTime = ss.getServerDateAndTime();
        if (systemSettingsBean == null || systemSettingsBean.getDateValue() == null) {
            systemSettingsBean = new SystemSettingBean();
            systemSettingsBean.setDateValue(serverDateAndTime);

            date = cal.getTime();
        } else {
            //........
            if (numberOfChanges == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        publishProgress(1);
 //........
        publishProgress(5);
        //........
        publishProgress(4);
         //........

        publishProgress(4);
         //........
        publishProgress(4);
         //........

        publishProgress(4);
         //........

        publishProgress(4);
         //........

        publishProgress(4);
         //........

        publishProgress(5);
        //........

        publishProgress(5);
        //........

        publishProgress(5);
        //........

//       //........
        publishProgress(5);
         //........


        publishProgress(5);
        //........

        publishProgress(5);
         //........
        publishProgress(5);
        //........

        publishProgress(5);
        //........

        publishProgress(5);
         //........

        publishProgress(5);
         //........

        publishProgress(5);
         //........

        publishProgress(5);
        //........

        publishProgress(5);
        //........

        if (successfullSync) {
             //........
        }
        publishProgress(5);
        return successfullSync;
    }
}
```

Also the code for the interface:

import android.content.Context;

```
public interface ISyncronizable {

    public Context getContext();
    public void updateProgress(int progress);
    public void finishedSyncronization(boolean isSuccessfullyFinished);
}
```

Strange is the fact that using this code the progress is visible:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (getActivity());
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setTitle(saveTitle);
        progressDialog.setMessage(saveDescription);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: Update your question with the snippet where progress is being updated. Have you tried logging the value of `int progress`?

Comment: this part is fine because i am using the progress in two sides of my application. The same interfaces which handle the progress is called inside PrefFragment (the above code) and in the LoginFragment. For the login fragment the progress works fine but i am using an TextView for showing the progress.

Comment: could you please show your SyncAsyncTask source

Comment: no. but the issue is not there

Comment: @Mike I updated the question and I deleted my answer.

Comment: Provide the code for your instance of `ISyncronizable`. If that is your `Activity` or `Fragment`, what does its `updateProgress()` method look like? Have you verified it is being called and is properly updating the progress dialog?

Comment: The updateProgress(int i) is listed above.

Comment: try removing the `incrementProgressBy()` since you are already setting the progress value above it.  It's possible the two are interfering with each other.

Comment: i did. Has the same result like `   progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
`I do not understand why in this case the progress is not visible.

Comment: You have set max =100 while you are setting progress as upto 5 using publishProgress.

Comment: And how should i set the progress?

Comment: Please add "@Sufian" in your comment. I came back here randomly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the value you pass to `publishProgress()`.

You have set max value of `ProgressBar` to be 100, therefore if you want to see any visible change to the progress, use 10, 20, 30, and so on instead.

So in your `doInBackground()` you will do something like this:

```
if (successfullSync) {
    publishProgress(100);
    //........
}
```